Мне нужна помощь с задачей по информатике 9 класс

Напишите программу для решения следующей задачи. У спортсменов силачей есть три попытки чтобы поднять вес. В следующий этап соревнований проходят спортсмены, хотя бы в одной попытке взявшие вес 100 кг.
Сколько спортсменов вышли в следующий этап?
Программа получает на вход количество спортсменов, принимавших участие в соревнованиях (1 ≤ N ≤ 100), затем для каждого спортсмена вес, который взял каждый из них в трех попытках - три числа, разделенные пробелом.
У меня постоянно проблемы с ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '80 90 100'

Ну и как строку "80 90 100" превратить в int? Может стоит разбить эту строку по пробелу и только потом каждый элемент превращать в int?

Проблема в вашем коде заключается в том, что вы пытаетесь преобразовать всю строку с тремя числами в одно целое число с помощью int(input()). Вместо этого вам нужно сначала разделить введенную строку на отдельные числа, а затем преобразовать каждое из них в целое число.
# Считываем количество спортсменов
n = int(input())

# Инициализируем счетчик спортсменов, прошедших в следующий этап
count = 0

# Обрабатываем данные для каждого спортсмена
for _ in range(n):
    # Считываем строку с результатами и разбиваем ее на отдельные числа
    weights = list(map(int, input().split()))
    
    # Проверяем, есть ли среди результатов вес 100 кг или больше
    if any(weight >= 100 for weight in weights):
        count += 1

# Выводим результат
print(count)

